# Next.js 13 Error: Byte Index Out of Bounds on 'npm run dev'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, installation, next.js13

To install `Next.js 13.4.12`, I am using the command `npx create-next-app@13.4.12`. Everything works fine and all the dependencies are installed with no problems. However as soon as I run the server `npm run dev`. I get this weird error -

```
byte index 6 is out of bounds of \ude
⨯ ./app/layout.tsx
Error: failed to process byte index 6 is out of bounds of \ude

Import trace for requested module:
./app/layout.tsx
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
```

Here is the screenshot for the installtion -
[image]

Here is the screenshot of the error -
[image]

The error log can be found on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/D2Ukn4ms). *(Please take a look if needed, I uploaded it to pastebin to not make a lot of clutter here)*

Please help me out with this I have tried a lot of things but unfortunately nothing seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

### 100% works

I had the same problem and the problem was **project folder name**

Its name shouldn't start with

> ude

and one possible solution is to **rename** your ***project folder*** or move it to a different path that does not start with “ude”.

Comment: This worked for me too. Any idea why the folder is not allowed to start with "ude"?

Answer (score 1):

I face exact this same problem,

So I change **folder name** --> form **"udemy-clone"** to **"tutorial-portal"** & 
in **package.json** file --> **"name": "tutorial-portal"**

& its work for me...

**NOTE:** not chose any name that stars with **"ude"**

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Tried downgrading the next version to 13.4.6 and it worked.

I had a week old project which was working and this was the difference between the old & the new one which I created today.

[image]

Comment: I tired doing this and it worked one time but I tried doing this again and it again shows me the same error :/

Comment: How are you creating the project? It would not work if you are running `npx create-next-app@13.4.12`. Install the `create-next-app@13.4.6` separately by running `npm i -g create-next-app`. Then create your app using `create-next-app <your-app>` . Your package.json should reflect v13.4.6 for next.

Answer (score 0):

try running on powershell. It helped me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating the project in the ex root directory. c:\projects\myapp. I believe that the compiler gets lost when trying to create the project in a folder within a user subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me (changing the directory; downgrading led to a separate crash). The current workaround I am using is to run Next.js in wsl2 (Ubuntu in my case).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I created the **NextJs** project inside a folder named "**udemy**".
After changing the folder name the issue was solved!

- Keep in mind, that the name of the folder or file should not start with "**ude**"
- it includes all the parent folders of the project, no parent folder should start with "**ude**"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I managed to solve the issue by REMOVING
**".next"** folder and run "npm run dev" again, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the tutorial was using `next` version `14.0.3`, so I changed that to `14.1.0`, ran `npm install` again and ran the project and it worked!